# Unresolved reference: ext when importing androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit, android-espresso

Recently, I've decided to update my Espresso code to use `ActivityScenarioRule` instead of the deprecated `ActivityTestRule`.

To do this, I've imported the following library into my project:

[image]

The final code using `ActivityScenarioRule`:

```
package com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.main

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.R
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith


@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class MainActivityTestsWhenNewProjectIsCreated {
    @get:Rule
    var activityTestRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    private fun createNewProject() {
        onView(withId(R.id.floatingActionButton)).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_projectTitleTextInputEditText)).perform(ViewActions.replaceText("Untitled Project"))
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_spanCountTextInputEditText)).perform(ViewActions.replaceText("5"))
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_doneButton)).perform(click())
    }

    @Test
    fun uitest_fragmentNewCanvasProjectTitleTextInputEditText_isNotDisplayed_after_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isPressed() {
        createNewProject()
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_projectTitleTextInputEditText)).check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())
    }

    @Test
    fun uitest_fragmentNewCanvasProjectTitleTextInputLayout_isNotDisplayed_after_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isPressed() {
        createNewProject()
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_projectTitleTextInputLayout)).check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())
    }

    @Test
    fun uitest_fragmentNewCanvasSpanCountTextInputEditText_isNotDisplayed_after_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isPressed() {
        createNewProject()
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_spanCountTextInputEditText)).check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())
    }

    @Test
    fun uitest_fragmentNewCanvasSpanCountTextInputLayout_isNotDisplayed_after_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isPressed() {
        createNewProject()
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_spanCountTextInputLayout)).check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())
    }

    @Test
    fun uitest_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isNotDisplayed_after_fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton_isPressed() {
        createNewProject()
        onView(withId(R.id.fragmentNewCanvas_doneButton)).check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the UI tests, I get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: ext
```

The error is coming from this line:

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
//    implementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
}
```

How can I fix this? This import statement was added automatically by Android Studio, and I'm confused why it's saying that 'ext' is an unresolved reference.

It's not that the code with `ActivityTestRule` *doesn't* work, I just wanted to switch to a safer alternative which seems to be `ActivityScenarioRule` - if I keep running into these problems I might need to revert back to the deprecated library.

Comment: What do your `build.gradle` file look like?

Comment: @dominicoder I edited my question to include that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Uhh, wait a second, I already have implementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0' included in my project... The commented out one is just a duplicate lol

You have it imported as `testImplementation` - it should be `androidTestImplementation`.

How you declare the dependency depends on what kind of tests are going to use it. `testImplementation` is for anything under `test/` (usually unit tests that don't depend on the Android framework). Anything that does depend on the Android framework goes under `androidTest/` and so would use `androidTestImplementation`:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
```